# Copy a file's contents while ignoring characters between < and > in Java

Tags: strip-tags

I'm looking to write a program that reads from a html file and copies the contents but it ignores the html tags without using replaceAll. Also the stripping of html tags must be done in a different method. The file looks like this :

```
 <html>
 <head>
 <title>My web page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
 <p>There are many pictures of my cat here,
 as well as my <b>very cool</b> blog page,
 which contains <font color="red">awesome
 stuff about my trip to Vegas.</p>


 Here's my cat now:<img src="cat.jpg">
 </body>
 </html>
```

And I'd like my program to display the following:

```
 My web page


 There are many pictures of my cat here,
 as well as my very cool blog page,
 which contains awesome
 stuff about my trip to Vegas.


 Here's my cat now:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```java
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String html = " <html>\n"
            + " <head>\n"
            + " <title>My web page</title>\n"
            + " </head>\n"
            + " <body>\n"
            + " <p>There are many pictures of my cat here,\n"
            + " as well as my <b>very cool</b> blog page,\n"
            + " which contains <font color=\"red\">awesome\n"
            + " stuff about my trip to Vegas.</p>\n"
            + "\n"
            + "\n"
            + " Here's my cat now:<img src=\"cat.jpg\">\n"
            + " </body>\n"
            + " </html>";

    boolean inTag = false;
    StringBuilder finalString = new StringBuilder();

    int length = html.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {

        char c = html.charAt(i);

        if ('<' == c) {
            inTag = true;
        } else if ('>' == c) {
            inTag = false;
        } else if (!inTag) {
            finalString.append(c);
        }

    }

    System.out.print(finalString);

}
```

Comment: Instead of just giving the code, you should explain what you're doing.